# compile error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnetlink

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, linker

I'm trying to compile some c code via make with gcc, but I keep getting:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnetlink
```

I have **-lnetlink** included in the gcc make parameters. Using **locate netlink** is able to find multiple items. I've even told gcc exactly where to find one by using **-L/usr/include/linux**, but it still gives the error.

The gcc command arguments below:

```
gcc -g -ggdb -Wall -Wextra  -o mt6d mt6d.o address_worker.o tunnel_worker.o mt6d_assoc.o addr_gen.o send_utils.o if_utils.o tun_utils.o icmp_utils.o utils.o  -lcrypto -lssl -lnetlink -lpthread -lnetfilter_queue
```

I've also been having errors with **libnetlink.h**, but was able to get them resolved, but I've included that here if that might be related and this error appears immediately after the other was fixed. Fixed by using **C_INCLUDE_PATH**

I've recently upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 and was using 11.04 before that.

Let me know if you need any more information. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
-Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to compile some c code via make with gcc, but I keep getting:

Technically, this stage is called linking.  That difference may seem subtle at first, but it's a really important one and can help frame the investigation when problems like this arise.

You should not reference `/usr/include` paths with `-L`. `-L` adds to the search path for libraries and generally only header files should show up under `/usr/include`.

`libnl` enables `pkg-config`, so you should use that.

For example (assuming you have `libnl-3-dev` installed):

```
gcc -o my_executable $(pkg-config --libs libnl-3.0) my_foo.o my_bar.o
```

In a `Makefile`, you could do the following to achieve that effect:

```
LDLIBS+=$(shell pkg-config --libs libnl-3.0)
CFLAGS+=$(shell pkg-config --cflags libnl-3.0)
```